# Ionic2 using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cordova, ionic2

I am having a problem when loading the VSEmulator, it says i am missing a file but i am not sure what to do to solve it?, or what to download. I do have Java installed and i can confirm that typing Java in the command prompt it shows the Java help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is platform configuration you use? android or ios?

Comment: it would be android

Comment: I'm suggest you to use Ionic CLI and working with Android emulators (HAXM), cuz, it will be faster and more simplest way. VS Emulator already is not actual for use